# How to use a CSS stylesheet file uploaded on the web in a local project?

Tags: html, css

I found a CSS file on the web but there was not any way to download the file.
I just know how to use a CSS file in my local project, not a file on the web.
How can I use this file on the web in my project?

**For Example : http://example.com**

Comment: Hi, could you say why you could not download the file? The problem with a solution that just loads it each time from the web where you found it is that it may get changed or removed - you really need to have your own copy for safety.

Answer (score -1):

You can include the link instead of a realtive path.
Here bootstrap e.g.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score -1):

just ned to use this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Your_stylesheet_Address">
```